# How do we set maximum HP for each character?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players

I'm with a very new group to D&D and we have the Starter Set for 5th edition and we don't really know how to set the character's health up. Where do I find the numbers/the procedure?

Comment: Do you mean Hit Point? Since Hit Points is not health.

Answer (score 6):

#### Give them the max HP roll for level 1 based on their hit dice, and add their Constitution Modifier.

This is 6 on a d6 for example, or 8 on a d8. If their Constitution Modifier is positive, add this to the Hit Dice number. If it is negative, **subtract** this from the Hit Dice number. This is their 1st level HP.

#### For subsequent levels, either roll their hit dice, or take the average, then add their Constitution Modifier again.

The average is half the hit dice's maximum plus one. For example, a d8's average is 5. Add the Constitution Modifier as described above. If instead we rolled, we would roll a d8, add the result then add the Constitution Modifier.

**Note:** In general all characters *should* use the same scheme of taking the Average, or Rolling, however this is **not required**, either by the rules, or for general effectiveness. Making sure everyone has the same system only prevents the case of "Rolling Resentment" when someone rolls a 1 on HP, while the person who took the average is sitting comfortably on more HP.

As a final note, as mentioned in a comment by **nitsua60** on a different answer, the Starter Set should come with 5 character sheets **already ready to go**, fully built, with HP, Spells, abilities, skills, etc, all selected and ready to go, along with a guide on the back of said sheets on how to level them from 1-4. If you're worried about marking the sheets, you can just make a photocopy, (That's what I did) or download them from [here](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/StarterSet_Charactersv2.pdf). (Thanks again to **nitsua60**)